# Gdal installation on Mac OS

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven, gdal

I’m trying to work with Gdal Library and Java in a Mac OS. But I’m new on Goal and I’m not able to make it works.

Also, I’m working with Maven. So I added this dependency on pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gdal</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdal</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

In order to test it on Eclipse I create a simple class like below:

```
import org.gdal.gdal.gdal;
import org.gdal.gdalconst.gdalconstConstants;
import org.gdal.ogr.ogr; 

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                gdal.AllRegister(); 
    }
}
```

When I execute I’m facing with the following error:

Native library load failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ogrjni in java.library.path

I tried to fix it all day without success. I just wanna know a simple way to execute Gdal into Eclipse.

**PS: I can run Gdal successfully on terminal**

Comment: Are you setting the "-Djava.libary.path=..." system property to a path containing the gdal shared libraries?

Comment: No. I Just added the maven dependency and installed gdal by brew. Should I set what path?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## GDAL installation

#### Install arguments

Make sure you have installed gdal with java and swig-java arguments.

> brew install gdal --with-java --with-swig-java

**ps: remove your current gdal installation before run the command above.**

You may need some additional arguments. Check all arguments using

> brew info gdal

Also, you can check the arguments available below.

> **--with-armadillo**
>
> Build with Armadillo accelerated TPS transforms.
>
> **--with-complete**
>
> Use additional Homebrew libraries to provide more drivers.
>
> **--with-java**
>
> Build with java support
>
> **--with-libkml**
>
> Build with Google's libkml driver (requires libkml --HEAD or >= 1.3)
>
> **--with-mdb**
>
> Build with Access MDB driver (requires Java 1.6+ JDK/JRE, from Apple or Oracle).
>
> **--with-mysql**
>
> Build with mysql support
>
> **--with-opencl**
>
> Build with OpenCL acceleration.
>
> **--with-postgresql**
>
> Build with postgresql support
>
> **--with-python3**
>
> Build with python3 support
>
> **--with-swig-java**
>
> Build the swig java bindings
>
> **--with-unsupported**
>
> Allow configure to drag in any library it can find. Invoke this at your own risk.
>
> **--without-python**
>
> Build without python2 support
>
> **--HEAD**
>
> Install HEAD version

#### Check gdal required dependencies

Check if you have installed all dependencies required by gdal. Use

> brew info gdal

to see all dependencies and if you have them installed.

> ==> Dependencies
>   Required: libpng ✔, jpeg ✔, giflib ✔, libtiff ✔, libgeotiff ✔, proj ✔, geos ✔, json-c ✔, libxml2 ✔, pcre ✔, sqlite ✔, freexl ✔, libspatialite ✔
>
> Optional: postgresql ✘, mysql ✔, armadillo ✔
>
> ==> Requirements
>   Build: java >= 1.7 ✔, fortran ✔, git ✔
>
> Optional: java >= 1.7 ✔, python3 ✔

## Maven configuration

If you're using maven on your project, you need to add gdal dependency in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.gdal</groupId>
   <artifactId>gdal</artifactId>
   <version>1.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

## Environment variable

You have to add environment variable in Eclipse, like [jdeolive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401396/jdeolive) said.

> Run > Run Configurations

then select your application in the left and go to Environment tab.

Add DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH pointing to /usr/local/opt/gdal/lib.

That's how I installed gdal and it's working perfectly on macOS 10.12.6.

Comment: Does not seem to work:
`Warning: gdal: this formula has no --with-java option so it will be ignored!
Warning: gdal: this formula has no --with-swig-java option so it will be ignored!
`

Comment: This no longer works.
brew no longer supports such options and the gdal package now has no such options.
You can see the options by running `brewinfo gdal`.
Currently I cannot see any way of automatically installing the java bindings via homebrew.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore 2022

Comment: Could you solve this issue? @rooby

Comment: @KanchanChowdhury: To get it working I had to build GDAL from source. The latest info for that is at https://gdal.org/development/building_from_source.html although I haven't done it for a long time as more recently I have been doing all my GDAL work on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the java.library.path system property when you run java. It must point to the directory containing the gdal shared libraries. I've also found that you may need to set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable as well.

I have gdal installed via homebrew and here is what I do:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/gdal/lib
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/opt/gdal/lib -cp gdal.jar ...
```

Comment: But, what is my "libs" folder. I'm mean, Am I looking for what kind of files? I have this question because I have any folders in gdal path

Comment: You're looking for libgdal.dylib if you're on OSX. I have GDAL installed via homebrew as well and it's located at /usr/local/opt/gdal/lib.